# How to get Data between a range of two dates in MongoDB Using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I need to get data from my MongoDB using Nodejs API .  I trying this

```
 const attendanceRecords = await Attendence.find({
      user: _id,
      currentDate: { $gte: fromDate, $lte: toDate },
    }).populate("user", "firstname lastname email");
```

But its not giving me correct data

currentDate field in my MongoDB database is date datatype and i am storing this date using this code

```
const mycurrentDate = new Date().toLocaleDateString('en-US', {
    day: '2-digit',  
    month: '2-digit',
    year: 'numeric',
 });
 
 const formattedDate = new Intl.DateTimeFormat("en-US", optionss).format(date);
```

the datatype of formattedDate is string Now how can I filter data and get data between a range of two dates ?

Comment: We need more information to assist. What are the values of `fromDate`and `toDate` when you're getting incorrect results? What documents are unexpectedly returned? Is this Mongoose and, if so, how is your model defined?

Answer (score 1):

This error is likely caused by trying to store Date type as string type and filtering them as Date type during the query.

```
const mycurrentDate = new Date(); // when you store to mongodb you should use Date type

let fromDate = new Date('2023-06-22'); // use Date type to filter
let toDate = new Date('2023-06-31'); // Date type
const attendanceRecords = await Attendence.find({
      user: _id,
      currentDate: { $gte: fromDate, $lte: toDate },
    }).populate("user", "firstname lastname email");
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume using Mongoose with node, the query will be like that!

```
> var startDate = new Date("2023-01-01");
var endDate = new Date("2023-12-31");

Modal_name.find({
  date_field_name: {
    $gte: startDate,
    $lte: endDate
  }
});
```

date_field_name your created_at field name in Collection

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).